# Um welche Sprachfigur handelt es sich hier?

Tags: idiom

Anstatt zu sagen "stell' dir vor, er sieht sie nicht" könnte man auch sagen "stell' dir vor er ruft sie an", denn eine kennzeichnende Eigenschaft des Telefonierens ist, dass man sich nicht sieht.

Comment: Es ist unklar, was genau die Frage ist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine *Konkretisierung*.

Comment: Gibt es diese Sprachfigur auch irgendwo erklärt? Hat es was damit zu tun: https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/schreibschule/stilmittel -> Synekdoche